# How do I go about increasing model complexity?

Tags: r, regression

I performed a simple linear regression on my data, but I want to increase the model complexity, using R.

I was told to use:

```
lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = n))
```

to increase the degree of the polynomial to $n$, but this doesn't seem right to me.

For example, I get different estimates and standard errors when I compare:

```
lm(y ~ x)
```

and

```
lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = 1))
```

Shouldn't they be the same? Sorry if this isn't much information.  Still learning R and statistics.

Comment: Please explain why you would want to make a model more complex.  Ordinarily that is not desirable: it is forced on us when we confront a model with data and find it does not fit well.  The problem then is to *improve* the model--but not for the sake of making it more complex!

Comment: @whuber Agreed! Conceptually, the purpose of a model is to reduce the complexity of the real world into something comprehensible. Not the other way around! A "more complex" model could be built by simply adding more "x or y variables". However... by "complex" do you mean, say, "larger", "more realistic", or "less understandable" (for its own sake), etc.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822535/fitting-polynomial-model-to-data-in-r That looks like it will answer the question that was asked. Whether the OP *should* do this is another question entirely.

Comment: Actually it was for a given problem that I'm trying to solve.  I was asked to increase to complexity to a polynomial of degree 16, then compare the RMSEs with the degrees of the polynomials.  The link @thecity2 pretty much helped me out!  Thanks guys!

Comment: I have heard R can be good for machine learning. But can I use it to train a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)?

Comment: @batmac The comment above should be moved to the main body of the question. To increase the _"model complexity"_ and _"to increase the complexity to a polynomial of degree 16"_ are two different things altogether.

Answer (score 1):

- There are many ways to increase model complexity. Using polynomial expansion is one way. Other ways include: 1. using other basis expansions, such as Fourier basis expansion. 2. using splines. Examples can be found in this post.  [What's wrong to fit periodic data with polynomials?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224990/whats-wrong-to-fit-periodic-data-with-polynomials)
- If you want to use 16th order polynomial, you may consider using orthogonal polynomial instead of raw polynomial. Reasons can be found in this post. [Why are there large coefficents for higher-order polynomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233414/why-are-there-large-coefficents-for-higher-order-polynomial/234196#234196)
- If you want to know why `lm(y~x)` and `lm(y~poly(x,1))`, you can try to use `model.matrix` function to see, how the basis expansion changed your data. Here is an example on `mtcars` data. Note, even the order is `1`, it changed your data.

  ```
  > head(model.matrix(mpg~wt,mtcars))
                    (Intercept)    wt
  Mazda RX4                   1 2.620
  Mazda RX4 Wag               1 2.875
  Datsun 710                  1 2.320
  Hornet 4 Drive              1 3.215
  Hornet Sportabout           1 3.440
  Valiant                     1 3.460
  > head(model.matrix(mpg~poly(wt,1),mtcars))
                    (Intercept)   poly(wt, 1)
  Mazda RX4                   1 -0.1096309987
  Mazda RX4 Wag               1 -0.0628232889
  Datsun 710                  1 -0.1646988925
  Hornet 4 Drive              1 -0.0004130092
  Hornet Sportabout           1  0.0408879112
  Valiant                     1  0.0445591041
  ```

**However, the fitted values does not change, if the order is 1**.

```
    > head(as.vector(lm(mpg~wt,mtcars)$fitted.values))
    [1] 23.28261 21.91977 24.88595 20.10265 18.90014 18.79325

    > head(as.vector(lm(mpg~poly(wt,1),mtcars)$fitted.values))
    [1] 23.28261 21.91977 24.88595 20.10265 18.90014 18.79325
```