# Is polynomial regression possible in H2O?

Tags: regression, python, polynomial, h2o

Is there a way to carry out polynomial regression $x + x^2$ in H2O (Python)?
What I have found about this is "interactions" option in GLM. However, I am not sure if this option yields polynomial regression as given here ([link](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/building-high-order-polynomials-with-glm-for-higher-accuracy/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to manually do the basis expansion, any package supports linear regression will support polynomial expansion.

When I say manual basis expansion I mean to create additional columns to your data. Suppose you have three data points are $x_1,x_2,x_3$, and the design matrix is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&\ x_1 & x_1^2 \\ 1& x_2 & x_2^2\\  1 &\ x_3 &x_3^2\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can find more examples of the basis expansion here.

[What's wrong to fit periodic data with polynomials?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224990/whats-wrong-to-fit-periodic-data-with-polynomials)

PS: what I suggested is called raw polynomials, which is not a good idea from numerical stability view. Orthogonal polynomial would be much better, and details can be found in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233414/why-are-there-large-coefficents-for-higher-order-polynomial/234196#234196)

Comment: Obligatory mention of natural cubic splines!